# SNMP service filed

Tags: snmp

Good day

My snmpd service sometimes crashed. To recover, I restarted the snmpd service. But not completely solve this problem. A couple of days later my service went down
Help please, how to solve this problem?

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-135-generic
      Architecture: x86-64


# systemctl status snmpd
● snmpd.service - Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon.
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Sat 2023-05-20 08:04:38 +06; 2 days ago
    Process: 3527063 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd -LOw -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -f -p /run/snmpd.pid (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
   Main PID: 3527063 (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
```

Comment: Is this service inside a docker container?  Because it looks like it doesn't have permission to read the docker container environments, and that's why it's failing.  Which suggests *perhaps* this is a Docker issue.

Comment: FYI:  Your provided details (*if correct*) tell us you're behind on applying security fixes & patches, as a fully-upgraded 20.04 system will report itself as 20.04.6 and not 20.04.5.  You can refer to https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ and see the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded in the week+ before that date.

Comment: I would like delete or  edit my questions. How can I do it ?

Comment: You can hit the [EDIT button](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1468877/edit) to edit your question (*likewise your answers too*) or I can see the button too given my *rep* gives me *edit* privileges. Sorry I'm not familiar with deleting questions (*I've only asked one & never deleted it*)